# Javascript, buttons, and nested divs

Tags: javascript, html, button

3 div's nested as shown below:

- servicesContainer

  - service-type

    - service

The servicesContainer div has a button to add a new service-type to the servicesContainer
The service-type div has a button to add a new service to that service-type

The javascript to add a new service-type to the servicesContainer works correctly, however the javascript to add a new service to the service-type does not, and just adds a new service to the first service-type.

Below is a link to what I currently have, I feel like I'm close, but just missing something obvious.
http://jsfiddle.net/gHbss/324/

```
function AddService ()
{
    var serviceDiv = document.createElement ("div");
    serviceDiv.setAttribute("id", "service");

    var serviceHTML = '<br><table border="1"><thead><tr><th colspan="3">&nbsp;</th></tr></thead><tbody id="service"><tr><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td></tr><tr><td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td></tr><tr><td>31</td><td>32</td><td>33</td></tr></tbody></table>';

    serviceDiv.innerHTML = serviceHTML;

    var container = document.getElementById("service-type");
    container.appendChild(serviceDiv);
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Dont use the same `id` every time you create a new `<div>`. Think about using a datastructure to hold your services and types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huX23/)

I changed your addService function to take an element.  I changed the onclick of your buttons to pass `this`.  In the addService, I then find the appropriate parentNode of the object passed in instead of searching for `document.getElementById("service-type");`

So, your '+ Service' button should now read:

```
<button onclick="AddService(this)">+ Service</button>
```

And your addService function should now read:

```
function AddService (el)
{
    var serviceDiv = document.createElement ("div");
    serviceDiv.setAttribute("id", "service");

    var serviceHTML = '<br><table border="1"><thead><tr><th colspan="3">&nbsp;</th></tr></thead><tbody id="service"><tr><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td></tr><tr><td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td></tr><tr><td>31</td><td>32</td><td>33</td></tr></tbody></table>';

    serviceDiv.innerHTML = serviceHTML;
    el.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(serviceDiv);
}
```

**EDIT:** Based on your comment, I made an updated [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huX23/2/).
The code change looks like so:

```
function AddService(el) {
    var ParEls = el.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes;
    var serviceDiv;
    for (var i = 0; i < ParEls.length; i++) {
        if (ParEls[i].id == "service") {
            serviceDiv = ParEls[i];
        }
    }
    var serviceHTML = serviceDiv.innerHTML;
    serviceHTML += '<br><table border="1"><thead><tr><th colspan="3">&nbsp;</th></tr></thead><tbody id="service"><tr><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td></tr><tr><td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td></tr><tr><td>31</td><td>32</td><td>33</td></tr></tbody></table>';
    serviceDiv.innerHTML = serviceHTML;
    el.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(serviceDiv);
}
```

Comment: You know that feeling when you feel like an idiot because you've been banging your head against a wall for an hour when the solution was way easier than you thought it was going to be? That's me right now! You, sir, deserve a cookie.

Comment: Gotta love when requirements change. Instead of creating a new service div, now I have to append the new table to the existing one, and I can't figure out how to go about that. Is there a way to search for a specific element in the current node?

Comment: @George, yes, you can use `.childNodes` to get the children of an element.  After that, you can iterate through checking for the id `service`.  After which you would want to save and append to it's current HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your service type ids are not unique enough. When you append the HTML it will look for the first instance of the service-type id.

Easiest option would be to give it a number as well (i.e. id="service-type1"). Then when you add the service it will have to check which "number" it is nested under to append to that div.

Comment: I'd rather not change the id's if I can help it because then I'd have to change the overwhelming majority of my code in rails.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on 'Add Service Type', you are creating a new div with same id (service-type). An id should always be unique. JS will always capture the first element with id='service-type' and append 'service' to it. You should create a new div with different ids and then on clicking 'Add Service' find the id of the container containing that button. Once that is done, you can add new 'Service' in that container.

Also, id should always be unique